# How to make piechart from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

I have created a shape (1,105) dataframe which has the classroom number as column name and the only row of the dataframe contains the total number of students in each classroom inside their appropriate column. I would like to make a piechart with as labels the column names and as data the corresponding number inside the first row.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted so far?

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `plt.pie` -- but you'll need to reshape your data first. This latter question is much harder to answer without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

To plot a pie chart from your DataFrame very simply, you can do:

```
df.transpose().plot.pie(subplots=True)
```

I tried it with this simple DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[24, 65, 13, 23, 10]], columns=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```